# Haskell - Lenses, use of 'to' function

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have the following code. I'd like to be able to modify the active player's life when given a game state. I came up with an `activePlayer` lens, but when I try and use it in combination with the `-=` operator I receive the following error:

```
> over (activePlayer.life) (+1) initialState 
<interactive>:2:7:
    No instance for (Contravariant Mutator)
      arising from a use of `activePlayer'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Contravariant Mutator)
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `activePlayer'
    In the first argument of `over', namely `(activePlayer . life)'
    In the expression: over (activePlayer . life) (+ 1) initialState``
```

and the code in question:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Scratch where

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Data.Sequence (Seq)
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

data Game = Game
    { _players :: (Int, Seq Player) -- active player, list of players
    , _winners :: Seq Player
    }
    deriving (Show)

initialState = Game
    { _players = (0, S.fromList [player1, player2])
    , _winners = S.empty
    }

data Player = Player
    { _life :: Integer
    }
    deriving (Show, Eq)

player1 = Player
    { _life = 10
    }

player2 = Player
    { _life = 10
    }

makeLenses ''Game
makeLenses ''Player

activePlayer
  :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) =>
       (Player -> f Player) -> Game -> f Game
activePlayer = players.to (\(i, ps) -> S.index ps i)
```

Each player takes their turn in order. I need to keep track of all the players at once as well as which is currently active, which is the reason for how I structured that, although I am open to different structures since I probably don't have the right one yet.

Comment: I think your problem is that the definition of `activePlayer` allows it to act as a getter, but not as a setter - you've told it how to pull a player out of the Sequence, but not how to change the active player - therefore it can't be used to modify players. Check out the type of `to` --- `> :i to` results in `to :: (a -> c) -> Getter a b c d`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you compose various items in the lens library with `(.)` they may lose capabilities according to a kind of subtyping (see below). In this case, you've composed a `Lens` (`players`) with a `Getter` (`to f` for some function `f`) and thus the combination is just a `Getter` while `over` acts on lenses that can both get and set.

`activePlayer` should form a valid lens, though, so you can just write it manually as a getter/setter pair. I'm writing it partially below under the assumption that the index can never be invalid.

```
activePlayer :: Lens' Game Player
activePlayer = lens get set 
  where
    get :: Game -> Player
    get (Game { _players = (index, seq) }) = Seq.index seq index

    set :: Game -> Player -> Game
    set g@(Game { _players = (index, seq) }) player = 
      g { _players = (index, Seq.update index player seq) }
```

To better understand the subtyping that's occurring in the `lens` library we can use [the Big Lattice Diagram from Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)

[image: the Big Lattice Diagram from Hackage]

Whenever you combine two lens types with `(.)` you end up with their first common descendent in that chart. So if you combine `Lens` and `Prism` you can see that their arrows converge on `Traversal`. If you combine `Lens` and `Getter` (of which `to f` is) then you get a `Getter` since `Getter` is a direct descendent of `Lens`.

Comment: Thanks, that diagram actually makes sense now. Was scary before. One possible typo, I think your type of set should be `Game -> Player -> Game` correct? At least, `Player -> Game -> Player` didn't type check when I tried it.

Comment: That diagram is kind of scary until you need it—and yup, typo precisely. That's what I get for not actually type-checking my own code. :)